# How do I bootstrap a WPF application using an ApplicationContext?

Tags: wpf, winforms

I don't know much about WPF, but my current project starts with an App.xaml which points to a main window (using the startupUri property).  I want to convert my WinForms tray app into WPF.  It makes use of the ApplicationContext.  A windowless component is created inside the TrayApplicationContext constructor.  Here is the bootstrapping code:

```
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {                      
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

                Application.Run(new TrayApplicationContext());             
        }
```

How do I effectively achieve the above with a WPF application?

Comment: Just set your main window's Visibility property to Hidden.

Comment: So is there no such thing as ApplicationContext with WPF?

Comment: Assuming WPF resembles Winforms is going to buy you a lot of hurt.  No.